# Job negotiation, Can I mention my expected raise after one year?

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation, entry-level

I'm a recent college grad with a degree in applied statistics.

Before accepting the job offer can I mention this:

In order to be a realistic long term fit, I want to bring to attention that I am interested in assuming the role of an inventory analyst at ABC. My area of study and problem solving skills are best utilized under the job description of an analyst.

I am willing to start off as an inventory associate and learn the details of the business. I estimate that 6-12 months will be ample time for me to understand the inventorial procedures of ABC and transition that knowledge into the position of an inventory analyst.

As an inventory analyst I will be seeking a base salary of 55,000.

The wording can definitely improve, it's just a rough.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how it is you, as a recent graduate, believe you know how long it will take for you to understand a companies procedures.  Questions you should research are: What experience (in terms of years/duties) does an inventory analyst position normally require?  What is the normal pay for that job?  I'd be hard pressed to hire someone that was attempting to dictate their future title and salary when they have yet to prove themselves at all.

Comment: I have shadowed at their company.

Comment: The average salary of a stats major is 55,000k

Comment: I know its a buyers market for jobs, but I rather not accept an offer that I would end up leaving after a years time, I want the company to know my goals so they can choose to hire me or not.

Comment: The thing you should take away from this is that it's not normal.  I'm not sure where you are getting the "average salary" from nor what it is even based off of, but if it's a salary site then you should take that with a grain of salt.  The wage you can get is based on so many different factors that trying to negotiate a future raise when they have no idea what you are actually capable of will be somewhere between difficult and impossible.  The normal way of doing things is to take the job, prove yourself THEN ask for more money when the review comes up.

Comment: If that "average salary" is from talking to people working at that company, then hopefully you asked a critical question which is: how long have *they* been doing this?  I hope you aren't expecting to make the exact same thing as someone who's been doing that job for 5+ years, because that is highly unlikely.

Comment: This isn't a normal situation, this offer is only feasible for me if I get the raise that i'm asking for.

Comment: I'm giving them at least a year's time to evaluate me. Also their operations are expanding and I know they could use my skills for the position. I would be the only recent grad at their facility, with a fresh perspective on all their operations. I want this job, but I have the ability to wait for a little longer.

Comment: 1. "average salary" of a statistics grad is not relevant to a specific role - otherwise a statistics grad who decides to work in a pub will be paid the same as a financial analyst in the City of London.

2. "average salary" of a specific role is almost meaningless - you can base expectations on the market value of entry-level and one-year experience, but ultimately, you will be offered what the company thinks you are worth and are prepared to pay to fill the role, not some "average".

Comment: that said - there's nothing inherently wrong with your plan, just don't be surprised if their expectations don't match yours

Comment: I will let you guys know, how my negotiation fared. I also believe that i am being demanding, but if I enter this industry, most of the details I will learn will not be able to transition to another industry. [They use a personalized software] The opportunity cost is high for me and that is why I want my salary to cover that cost for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well yes and no...

**Can you negotiate future raises**

Yes, you can. Honestly in many cases this isn't a bad idea depending on experience and job requirements. (it can be a hard sell though)

Instead of flat out saying after *duration of time* I expect a raise, and go through your justifications. I'd approach this more along the lines of, a this point you're entry level taking an entry level wage, you are ambitious and expect opportunities to advance as you expand your skill set and gain experience. You also expect the company to remain competitive in their offerings as you develop.

Essentially my concern as someone hiring is you're fighting for a raise before you even start... that's a red flag to me... the part about getting to know my systems, expanding and advancing on the other hand is a plus in my book. You're telling me not only do you want to stick around, but you want to adapt and grow in your role here.

The best you can probably do is get the manager on board with your ambitions to help you fast track if you can live up to the higher expectations that would demand. Your wage should increase in tune with those advancements. I will say though save asking for a raise until you've earned it, if you want to make sure you're in a company that does make sure to compensate their employees as they grow ask both the manager / HR person, and if possible someone who works there. Typically people who don't get reasonable compensation adjustments are VERY vocal about it.

Answer (score 1):

Best not to mention salary at the moment. You know what you want, but you don't know what they can give you. And you won't have an idea of what they can give you until you have worked there for a while and possibly talked to a few people who are familiar with the process. Even with something as seemingly straightforward as asking, there are right ways of asking and wrong ways of asking, and you won't know which is which until you have worked for the organization for a while.

An uninformed, unsupported demand is just that - a demand. It's not a negotiation. Because negotiations are conducted with a clear grasp as to what demands are possible and what demands are not. And your demand could blow up in your face if they decide they can't meet your demand.

I'd suggest that you say that you'd like a salary review after six months. When it comes to making demands, try to make demands and phrase them in a way that leaves you room to back out and back down if they get turned down.